# How to manipulate duplicated rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have duplicated a set of data, and I'd like to edit the rows I have duplicated by adding an 'A' to the duplicated rows and 'a' to the original rows under the column "Code". Example below.

**The reproducible data frame:**

```
Date <- c("2016-01-02","2016-01-03","2016-01-04")
Data <- c("0",".2", ".1")
Code <- c("", "", "")
y <- data.frame(Date, Data, Code)
y<- y[rep(row.names(y),2),]
y$Date <- as.Date(y$Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
y <- y[order(y$Date), ]
```

**The current data:**

```
> y
        Date    Data    Code
1   2016-01-02    0     
1.1 2016-01-02    0     
2   2016-01-03   .2     
2.1 2016-01-03   .2     
3   2016-01-04   .1     
3.1 2016-01-04   .1
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
> y
      Date      Data     Code
1   2016-01-02    0       a
1.1 2016-01-02    0       A
2   2016-01-03   .2       a
2.1 2016-01-03   .2       A
3   2016-01-04   .1       a
3.1 2016-01-04   .1       A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`duplicated(y)` returns a boolean vector with FALSE if a row is encountered for the first time, and TRUE if a row is duplicated. You could use that as follows:

```
y$Code = ifelse(duplicated(y),"A","a")
```

Output:

```
          Date Data         Code
1   2016-01-02    0            a
1.1 2016-01-02    0            A
2   2016-01-03   .2            a
2.1 2016-01-03   .2            A
3   2016-01-04   .1            a
3.1 2016-01-04   .1            A
```

There is no need to create the column beforehand in `y <- data.frame(Date, Data, Code)`, so that could become: `y <- data.frame(Date, Data)`

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! I wanted to also try doing the same manipulation to the Data column... where the original is zero, but the duplicated is the value. But it doesn't seem to work when I try `y$Data <- ifelse(duplicated(y),y$Data,0)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Then you can put `y[order(y$Data==0,decreasing=TRUE),]` before running my statement. That way, all zeros will be at the top, and will be counted as the original.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! y$Data <- ifelse(y$Code=="A",y$Data,0). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great that you were able to resolve the issue yourself, glad that I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Or You can try `group` from `dplyr` , Just in case you have more than two duplicated in each Date

```
y%>%group_by(Date)%>%dplyr::mutate(code=ifelse(row_number()==1,'a','A'))
#y%>%group_by(Date)%>%dplyr::mutate(code=ifelse(row_number()%%2==0,'A','a')) more than 2 
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Date [3]
        Date   Data   Code  code
      <date> <fctr> <fctr> <chr>
1 2016-01-02      0            a
2 2016-01-02      0            A
3 2016-01-03     .2            a
4 2016-01-03     .2            A
5 2016-01-04     .1            a
6 2016-01-04     .1            A
```

For example :

```
y<- y[rep(row.names(y),3),]
y$Date <- as.Date(y$Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
y <- y[order(y$Date), ]

y%>%group_by(Date)%>%dplyr::mutate(code=ifelse(row_number()%%2==0,'A','a')

    # A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   Date [3]
        Date   Data   Code  code
      <date> <fctr> <fctr> <chr>
1 2016-01-02      0            a
2 2016-01-02      0            A
3 2016-01-02      0            a
4 2016-01-03     .2            a
5 2016-01-03     .2            A
6 2016-01-03     .2            a
7 2016-01-04     .1            a
8 2016-01-04     .1            A
9 2016-01-04     .1            a
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R alternative with indexing is

```
y$Code <- c("a", "A")[duplicated(y) + 1]
```

which returns

```
y
          Date Data Code
1   2016-01-02    0    a
1.1 2016-01-02    0    A
2   2016-01-03   .2    a
2.1 2016-01-03   .2    A
3   2016-01-04   .1    a
3.1 2016-01-04   .1    A
```